# In Table Filter vs Filter Panels

Tags: tables, filter, data-tables

I have a question regarding In Table Filter vs Filter Panels. Context is for extremely complex data tables.

If a table has Filter Panels, would it be useful to still retain In Table Filters? If so, can you give me a use case as to why and companies that might do this? 
Just to be clear - by In Table filters I mean when there is a filter on each column of a data table. (Note: filters in the In Table Filter would sometimes overlap with the ones in the Filter Panel)

I've given this some thought and have my own idea here, but don't want to influence what everyone else might think. More so exploring this idea.

Thank you!

Comment: Please add a few mockups you made for better understanding of the context and the progress you have made so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Filter Panel:**

Assuming users find filter panel through a trigger "Add/Apply Filter" which is clear enough on the interface should complete the user task.

**In table filter**

The common interaction around the column header is the sorting operation. Do you have more touchpoints around each column? E.g re-name a field, edit field description, group by this field etc? Then, its good to include add filter here as well. If you don't have any such touchpoints around the column header, you can get rid of it.